# Javascript - Drop Down not showing all selections

Tags: javascript, dropdown

First, I am a rookie with JavaScript. So, in SharePoint using a web part, the drop down for D Jobs will not show all select-able items. It appears to only show 100 select-able items, but is needs to show all 150 items in the drop down. I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://Sharepoint/SiteAssets/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://SharePoint/SiteAssets/HillbillyCascade.js"></script>   

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      
            var cascadeArray = new Array();
            
            cascadeArray.push({
                  parentFormField: "Shop", //Display name on form of field from
parent list
                  childList: "D Jobs", //List name of child list
                  childLookupField: "Title", //Internal field name in Child List
used in lookup
                  childFormField: "D Job", //Display name on form of the child
field
                  parentFieldInChildList: "Shop0", //Internal field name in Child
List of the parent field
                  firstOptionText: "(Filtered by Shop)", dropDownItemCount:"999"
//Number of Items to Display on dropdown to remove 100 item limitation
            });
                 
            $().HillbillyCascade(cascadeArray);

});

</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74777/list-api-get-all-items-limited-to-100-rows

Comment: I'm not sure. i'm just trying to learn Java. The current drop down will not show all 150 items. I thought the dropdownitemcount would have allowed all to show, but it does not.

Comment: Java isn't javascript :) I think you need the code in `HillbillyCascade.js`, since it appears to be where the fetch occurs. If you have access to that, I would first check where `dropDownItemCount` is used, and then try adding a `$top=` with a limit over 100 manually.

Comment: I do not see dropDownItemCount in HillbillyCascade.js and I', not sure where to put it.

Comment: I can post the code if needed.

Comment: Its long and would post it in pieces if needed

Comment: Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You can link a text dump, but I'm not sure if I'll be able to help; all I can say is I would look at the URL being requested, and whether it has the query param `top` or `limit` (and if the latter, switch it to top).

Answer (score 1):

`src="https://SahrePoint/SiteAssets/HillbillyCascade.js"></script>`
I see a typo `Sahre` it should be `Share`

Comment: Good catch! Thanks, I will see if that fixes it>

Comment: Unfortunately, That did not fix it.